# SAP data extraction through BAPI file in Automation Anywhere

Tags: automation, rpa, sap-erp, automationanywhere, bapi

I am working in automation anywhere enterprise client where i have to extract SAP data with the help of BAPI files and dump it to the .csv file, when there is no parameter or filters for selected BAPI then its works fine, but the problem is if we have to pass any parameter or filters its not working and it always generate blank csv file,

How to extract SAP data through BAPI file when we have to pass the parameter values?

i am using Automation Anywhere community edition.

[image: AA BAPI selected window]

Comment: So, the software does not work as intended? Would it be more effective to contact the vendor directly? There are other tools to solve your problem but it looks like you only want to resolve the issue with this particular tool, then I would suggest contacting the software company directly.

Comment: It seems that your `$vCustomerID$` variable is not resolved to its value

Comment: @Suncatcher, No, the variable have the value. i already checked it.

Comment: "Have the value" and "not resolved to value" is different things, maybe the syntax used in this windows is wrong

Comment: NO, If i pass the value hard coded without any variable still the issue remains .